# Optimize relatedTo query

Tags: performance, relatedto, speed

Given:

Channel: Nutrition. 550k entries. It has entries field pointing to the "restaurants" channel.

Channel: Restaurants. 300k entries.

I'm trying to display restaurants that have at least one nutrition associated with them. Currently using the following snippet:

```
                {% set nutritionIds = craft.entries ({
                    section: 'nutrition',
                }).ids() %}

                {% set entries = craft.entries ({
                    section: 'restaurants',
                    orderBy: 'title',
                    limit: 40,
                    relatedTo: {
                        sourceElement: nutritionIds,
                    }
                }) %}
```

Please help me to optimize this query. Page load time is 50 seconds, memory usage is 250mb. Dedicated server.

Comment: As a last resort, you could write a job that compiles a single optimized database table (or two). A lot of effort but you will bypass all of Craft complexity guaranteeing a very fast query.

Answer (score 1):

Are the `nutrition` entries associated with `restaurant` entries through a single field or multiple fields? If it's only one field and you only want to query for restaurants that have *any* nutrition associated with them, you don't need to load all the IDs. Instead, you can just use `:notempty:` to find restaurants where the nutrition entries field is not empty. Assuming your entries field is named `nutrition`:

```
{% set restaurants = craft.entries()
    .section('restaurants')
    .orderBy('title')
    .limit(40)
    .nutrition(':notempty:')
    .all()
%}
```

See [Querying Elements with Entries Fields](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries-fields.html#querying-elements-with-entries-fields) in the documentation.

Now if the relation to nutrition entries is spread across *multiple* fields, you'll probably have to write a [custom where clause](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/element-queries.html#advanced-element-queries) to achieve the same result.

Comment: Moritz, entries in the restaurants channel have no relations (entries field) to nutrition. Instead, all entries in the nutrition channel are associated to a restaurant. https://i.imgur.com/F6knHlU.png

Comment: @MarkH. Ah I didn't catch that, that's unfortunate. In this case, you could use a custom `innerJoin()` statement to the `relations` table to filter out any restaurants that don't have a relation in that field. I've recently done something similar, see the final code example [in my question here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/38207/find-related-entries-by-specific-position-in-the-entries-field). If that doesn't work is is still not fast enough, you could give the [Reverse Relations](https://plugins.craftcms.com/reverserelations) plugin a try to be able to filter like that.